# Determine whether a string contains an Integer or a Float in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I get some input as a string, and I would like to know whether it contains an `Integer` or a `Float`.

For example:

```
input_1 = "100"
input_2 = "100.0123"
```

Now, let's take into account the following:

```
input_1.respond_to?(:to_f) # => true 
input_1.is_a?(Float)       # => false
input_1.is_a?(Fixnum)      # => false
input_1.to_f?              # => 100.0

input_2.respond_to?(:to_i) # => true
input_2.is_a?(Integer)     # => false
input_2.is_a?(Fixnum)      # => false
input_2.to_i               # => 100
```

In the cases above, we can't actually determine whether the string contains an `Integer` or a `Float`.  Is there a way in Ruby to determine whether a string contains a `Fixnum` or `Float`?

Comment: You could always just test to see if the string has a "." in it. BTW, do you want "100.00" to be counted as an integer or a float?

Comment: @Adrian that would be counted as a float.

Comment: "1.3" is contained in "ab1.3cd". Is that what you mean, or do you want to know if your string `str` equals the representation of an integer or float (i.e, does there exist an integer or float `n` such that `n.to_s == str`)?

Comment: Will your "strings" always be ONLY the value (`"123"` or `"1.23"`) or will the value be embedded inside non-digits (`"ab 1.23 cd"`)?

Comment: Why the rush selecting an answer?? I expect others are still working on solutions. Also, kindly answer the questions raised in the comments (by editing your question).

Comment: The best way is to convert it to the target class and catch any exception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
n = '100.0'

if n =~ /\A\d+\z/
  puts 'integer'
elsif n =~ /\A\d+\.\d+\z/
  puts 'float'
else
  puts 'not integer or float'
end
```

Edit regular expressions to taste.

Comment: or "-2" for a negative integer?

Comment: Those two examples are why I said "edit regular expressions to taste."

Comment: Adrian: "Edit regular expressions to taste." is not good enough. Negative numbers are easy to deal with but @tadman's comment brings into question whether regex is the way to go here.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to do this is the `Integer` and `Float` methods.

```
Integer("100")
100
Integer("1.03")
# ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1.03"
Float("1.03")
1.03
Float("1.2e9")
1200000000.0
Float("100")
100.0
```

You can make methods out of these like so:

```
class String
  def is_int?
    Integer(self) && true rescue false
  end

  def is_float?
    Float(self) && true rescue false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should capture the various ways of expressing numbers as strings:

```
%w[
  1
  1.0
  0xDEADBEEF
  0b1010
  1e10
  1.2e10
  -1
  -1.2
  a1
  a1.0
].each do |str|
  type = begin
           :integer if Integer(str)
         rescue ArgumentError
           begin
            :float if Float(str)
           rescue ArgumentError
            :neither
           end
         end
  type # => :integer, :float, :integer, :integer, :float, :float, :integer, :float, :neither, :neither
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is the representation of an integer or float (ie., if the string `str` can be obtained by converting an integer or float to `str`):

```
def integer_or_float?(str)
  :integer if Integer(str) rescue :float
end

integer_or_float? "-123"  #=> :integer
integer_or_float? "12.3"  #=> :float
integer_or_float? "1.2e9" #=> :float
```

If the string may not be the representation of an integer or float:

```
def integer_or_float?(str)
  :integer if Integer(str) rescue (:float if Float(str) rescue nil)
end

integer_or_float? "-123"  #=> :integer
integer_or_float? "12.3"  #=> :float
integer_or_float? "1.2e9" #=> :float
integer_or_float? "1.2x"  #=> :nil
```

Comment: `integer_or_float?("pool floaties") #=> :float`

Comment: @Max, "pool floaties" are clearly floats. Note I initially demanded integer or float, then was doing the edit when you left the comment.