# How to Determine if a given User input is a Float, String, or a Integer in Ruby

Tags: rubymine

The `is_a?` method doesn't work; I have tried it and it apparently it checks if the value is derived from an object or something.

I tried something like this:

```
printf "What is the Regular Price of the book that you are purchasing?"
regular_price=gets.chomp

if regular_price.to_i.to_s == regular_price
  print "Thank You  #{regular_price}"
  break
else
  print "Please enter your price as a number"
end
```

Can someone explain to me more what `.to_i` and `.to_s` do? I just thought they convert the user input to a string, or a Numerical Value. I actually don't know how to check input to see if what he put in was a float, a String, or a decimal.

I just keep getting Syntax errors. I just want to know how to check for any of the 3 values and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go through each of your questions and try to provide answers to point you in the right direction.

The `is_a?` method [works by accepting a class as a parameter and returning boolean](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F). For example:

```
'foo'.is_a?(String)
=> true

1234.is_a?(Integer)
=> true

'foo'.is_a?(Integer)
=> false

1234.is_a?(String)
=> false

1.234.is_a?(Float)
=> true
```

The `.to_i` method is [defined on the String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) and will convert a string to an Integer. If there is no valid integer at the start of the string then it will return `0`. For example:

```
"12345".to_i             #=> 12345
"99 red balloons".to_i   #=> 99
"0a".to_i                #=> 0
"hello".to_i             #=> 0
```

The `.to_s` [method on the `Integer` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_s) will return the string representation of the Integer. For example:

```
1234.to_s
=> '1234'
```

The same is true of `Float`:

```
1.234.to_s
=> '1.234'
```

Now let's take a look at your code. When I run it I get `SyntaxError: (eval):4: Can't escape from eval with break` which is happening because `break` has nothing to break out of; it isn't used to break out of an `if` statement but is instead used to break out of a block. For example:

```
if true
  break
end
```

raises an error. But this does not:

```
loop do
  if true
    break
  end
end
```

The reason is that calling `break` says "break out of the enclosing block," which in this case is the `loop do ... end` block. In the previous example there was no block enclosing the `if` statement. You can find more detailed explanations of the behavior of `break` [elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4601631/3784008).

Your final question was "I just want to know how to check for any of the 3 values and handle them accordingly." [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31569852/3784008) explains how to do that but the code example is written in a way that's hard to decipher, so I've rewritten it below in an expanded form to make it clear what's happening:

```
regular_price = gets.chomp

begin
  puts Integer(regular_price)
rescue
  begin
    puts Float(regular_price)
  rescue
    puts 'please enter your price as an Integer or Float'
  end
end
```

What this code does is first it attempts to convert the string `regular_price` to an Integer. This raises an exception if it can't be converted. For example:

```
Integer('1234')
=> 1234

Integer('1.234')
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1.234"

Integer('foo')
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "foo"
```

If an exception is raised then the `rescue` line stops the exception from being raised and instead continues executing on the next line. In this case, we're saying "if you can't convert to `Integer` then `rescue` and try to convert to `Float`." This works the same way as converting to `Integer`:

```
Float('1.234')
=> 1.234

Float('foo')
ArgumentError: invalid value for Float(): "foo"
```

Finally, we say "if you can't convert to `Float` then `rescue` and show an error message."